# Particle Info Node in a Different Object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, particles, smoke-simulation

So to put it simply, I am trying to create a particle system that emits particles, of course, in a stream and I have a smoke simulation set up so that the particles are on fire. The fire changes color as the particles are "alive" longer. Of course with a smoke sim, you give the domain a material, not the flow object.

My problem is that the flow object has the particle system therefore the particle info node for that system can only be used for that object (if I understand how the particle info node works) but I need to use the particle info from the flow object in my domain material.

Is there any way to do this without any weird scripting stuff or something?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a exacly soution for your question. But there is a way to do something like that... Instead of using the Particle Livetime you can use the heat Attribute, a Math noder and the ColorRamp.

1. Rename the Attribute "color" in "heat" (or add a blank Attribute node)
2. Add a Math node, change to multiply
3. Enter a colorramp
4. Connect the Colorramp with the color input of Volume Scatter and Volume Absortion.
5. Play with the value of the Multiply Node and the Positions inside the Colorramp
6. If you want thicker Smoke increase the Multiply Value of the density
7. also play with the temperature settings of the Domain, and Flow

If you know a better way, let me know....

[image]

[image]